# Using a for loop in server side code to cycle through labels by dynamically creating the names there

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was working on a website that had a list of asp labels.  I used javscript code to get the name of each box so I could modify the text that was inside them.  I was using a for loop similiar to this, and I became curious if there was a way to call all the labels similiarly so that you can put them in a loop and to cycle through them all.  Something like this in the server side code:

asp code:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblWorld1" Text="" />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblWorld2" Text="" />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblWorld3" Text="" />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblWorld4" Text="" />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblWorld5" Text="" />
```

c# code

```
for(int c = 1; c <= 5 ; c++)

{

  var label = "lblWorld" + c.toString();

  label.Text = "Hello World!";

}
```

However, in the server side code, this doesn't work.  Is there a way to make a for loop and with a dynamic system getting the name of the labels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Put all of the labels into some container, such as a `Panel` or `PlaceHolder`.  Give that container an ID.
2. In your code get the container by ID.
3. Iterate the `Controls` collection of that container to get each of the labels.  Use `OfType<Label>` if it's possible for there to be other types of controls besides labels.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow through with your current logic with:

```
for(int c = 1; c <= 5 ; c++)
{
var label = "lblWorld" + c.toString();
Label tempLabel = new Label;
tempLabel.ID = label.ToString();
tempLabel.Text = "Hello World!";   
}
```

You'll still need to deal with assigning values to individual labels though, so it's probably more scalable to handle the labels as a container.